# python sort by last word in line, different length lines

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have a file that has between 1 or 4 words per line, and I want to sort by the third word in the line. The below code does not work if there isn't a word in the s[2] slot. Is there anything I can do to still sort everything does? Thanks

```
with open('myfile.txt') as fin:
lines = [line.split() for line in fin]
lines.sort(key=lambda s: s[2])
```

Comment: add `try` and `except` for sort line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

‏You may want to try using the slice syntax

```
with open('myfile.txt') as fin:
    lines = [line.split() for line in fin]
    lines.sort(key=lambda s: s[2:3]) # will give empty list if there is no 3rd word
```

Comment: I will mark this right as it did its job, but now i have an issue where the blank values are sorted on top, ( empty, a, ..., z) is there anything i can do to put the empty at end ( a, ... , z, empty) Thanks!

Comment: @KirilAlexBallow - lines.sort(key=lambda s: s[2:3] or ["z"*100])  #not tested

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x.sort(key=lambda s: s[2] if len(s) > 2 else ord('z')+1)
```

That way if there is no s[2] it returns the next thing after 'z' (presumably the last ascii character value in your strings).  Feel free to change ord('z')+1 to some other large number

Answer (score 0):

```
def sortFileByLastWords(fIn, fOut):
    with open (fIn) as fin:
        lines = [line.split () for line in fin]
        lines.sort (key=lambda s: s[-1]) # make the last word of each line be the key
    with open (fOut, "w")  as fout:
        for film in lines:
            fout.write (' '.join (film) + '\n')
```